# How to lookup through an Array in MongoDB and Project Names From a Certain Collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have two collections, one named Exports and one named Service. Inside the Exports collection there is an object that holds inside of it an array of servicesIds.

I want to aggregate and lookup for the corressponding matching _ids from the Exports collection with the Service collection to find the name of the services.

The structure of the each document for the two collection is as follows:

Exports:

```
{
    "_id" : "818a2c4fc4",
    "companyId" : "7feb1812d8",
    "filter" : {
        "servicesIds" : [
            "0111138dc679d",
            "0c18c499435e9",
        ],
       
    },
    "_created_at" : ISODate("2019-10-27T09:06:03.102+0000"),
    "_updated_at" : ISODate("2019-10-27T09:06:05.099+0000"),
}
```

Service:
An example of one document with its _id is a foreign key inside the filters object then inside the servicesIds array

```
{
    "_id" : "0111138dc679d",
    "name" : "Bay Services",
    "character" : "B",
    "company" : {
        "id" : "f718a1c385",
        "name" : "xxx"
    },
    "active" : true,
    "tags" : [

    ],
    "_created_at" : ISODate("2020-04-09T06:36:14.442+0000"),
    "_updated_at" : ISODate("2020-06-06T03:52:16.770+0000"),
}
```

How can i do that?

Here is what i tried, but it keeps giving me and error reading

```
Mongo Server error '$in requires an array as a second argument, found: missing' on server
```

Here is my code:

```
db.getCollection("Exports").aggregate([
 
   {
       "$match": { "companyId":"818a2c4fc4" },
   },
   
   {
    "$lookup": {
    "from": "Service",
    "let":{ id : "$_id" },
    "pipeline": [
      {
          "$match": 
          {
          "$expr": 
              {
              "$in": ["$$id","$filter.servicesIds"]
              }
          }
      }
    ],
    "as":"services"
          }
      },
  
 ])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$unwind` the array first, or you can edit your answer with an expected result you want, then I will correct my answer.

```
db.Exports.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "companyId": "7feb1812d8"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$filter.servicesIds"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Service",
      "localField": "filter.servicesIds",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "docs"
    }
  }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/l2VweVYz1Fy

Comment: thank you for your answer, it is correct, the only wrong thing is that you added the $unwind stage before the lookup. that is wrong because it will spread the filter.servicesIds array and thats not what i need, however it helped me find the solution. Thank you!